# SqlCommand: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'

Tags: sql, asp.net

I'm trying to get  data from database show it in a ASP.NET `DataGrid`.

It's showing the above mentioned error.

This is the select command:

```
  public MasterJobList GetListForGrid(int RecCount, int PageNo, string OrderBy)
        {
            strSql = "WITH TempTable AS(Select JobDetails.JobCode,JobDetails.CurrentStatus,MasterModel.Name As ModelNumber,MasterModel.Code As ModelCode,MasterBrand.Code As BrandCode,MasterBrand.Name As BrandName,MasterDeviceType.Code As DeviceCode,MasterDeviceType.Name As DType,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY " + OrderBy + ") AS RowNumber From JobDetails JobDetails Inner Join MasterDeviceType ON JobDetails.DType = MasterDeviceType.Code Inner Join MasterBrand ON JobDetails.BCode = MasterBrand.Code Inner join MasterModel ON JobDetails.ModelNumber = MasterModel.Code WHERE 1 = 1) SELECT * FROM TempTable WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN {2} AND {3}";  
            MasterJobList objList = new MasterJobList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = objDB.GetDataTableFromSQL(strSql);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow Dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    jobs obj = new jobs();
                    obj.JobCode =Convert.ToInt32(Dr["JobCode"].ToString());

                    if (Dr["DType"] != DBNull.Value)
                        obj.DType = Dr["DType"].ToString();
                    else
                        obj.DType = "";

                    if (Dr["BrandName"] != DBNull.Value)
                        obj.BrandName = Dr["BrandName"].ToString();
                    else
                        obj.BrandName = "";

                    if (Dr["ModelNumber"] != DBNull.Value)
                        obj.ModelNumber = Dr["ModelNumber"].ToString();
                    else
                        obj.ModelNumber = "";

                    if (Dr["CurrentStatus"] != DBNull.Value)
                        obj.CurrentStatus = Dr["CurrentStatus"].ToString();
                    else
                        obj.CurrentStatus = "";

                  objList.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            return objList;
        }
```

The exact error is:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

Please look my full code...

Comment: The error message seems specific.  Why not copy the contents of strSql into Query Analyzer or SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: If I choose only select query its working on sql server management studio.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ROW_NUMBER`-"column" comes after the `JOIN`s.

Change it to:

```
string sql = @"
WITH TempTable AS 
(
    Select 
       JobDetails.JobCode,
       JobDetails.CurrentStatus,
       MasterModel.Name As ModelNumber,
       MasterModel.Code As ModelCode,
       MasterBrand.Code As BrandCode,
       MasterBrand.Name As BrandName,
       MasterDeviceType.Code As DeviceCode,
       MasterDeviceType.Name As DType,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {0}) AS RowNumber
    From JobDetails JobDetails  
    Inner Join MasterDeviceType 
       ON JobDetails.DType = MasterDeviceType.Code 
    Inner Join MasterBrand 
       ON JobDetails.BCode = MasterBrand.Code 
    Inner join MasterModel 
       ON JobDetails.ModelNumber = MasterModel.Code, 
    WHERE {1}
) 
SELECT * FROM TempTable WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN {2} AND {3}";
```

Now use `sql = String.Format(sql, orderBy, filter, rnStart, rnEnd)` to assign the values.

The variables could be:

```
string orderBy = "ModelNumber ASC";
string filter  = "BrandName = 'Sony'";
int rnStart = PageNo == 1 ? 1 : ((PageNo - 1) * RecCount) + 1;
int rnEnd   = PageNo == 1 ? RecCount : PageNo * RecCount;
```

---

**Update**: to show the complete method (at least the relevant code) according to your edit.

```
public MasterJobList GetListForGrid(int RecCount, int PageNo, string OrderBy)
{
    string strSql = @"
WITH TempTable AS 
(
    Select 
       JobDetails.JobCode,
       JobDetails.CurrentStatus,
       MasterModel.Name As ModelNumber,
       MasterModel.Code As ModelCode,
       MasterBrand.Code As BrandCode,
       MasterBrand.Name As BrandName,
       MasterDeviceType.Code As DeviceCode,
       MasterDeviceType.Name As DType,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {0}) AS RowNumber
    From JobDetails JobDetails  
    Inner Join MasterDeviceType 
       ON JobDetails.DType = MasterDeviceType.Code 
    Inner Join MasterBrand 
       ON JobDetails.BCode = MasterBrand.Code 
    Inner join MasterModel 
       ON JobDetails.ModelNumber = MasterModel.Code, 
    WHERE {1}
) 
SELECT * FROM TempTable WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN {2} AND {3}";

    int rnStart = PageNo == 1 ? 1 : ((PageNo - 1) * RecCount) + 1;
    int rnEnd   = PageNo == 1 ? RecCount : PageNo * RecCount;
    strSql = String.Format(strSql, OrderBy, "1=1", rnStart, rnEnd);

    DataTable dt = objDB.GetDataTableFromSQL(strSql);
    // ...
    return objList;
}
```

Comment: one more error comes up now "Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '0'.
Incorrect syntax near '2'."

Comment: @NAJEEB: have you noticed my comment at the end of my answer?

Comment: @NAJEEB: note that i've edited my answer, now it's hopefully more clear.

Comment: No errors now , but nothing is showing on grid(there is data in table)

Comment: @NAJEEB: do you get rows if you modify `rnStart` and `rnEnd` to `1` and `100`? However, what is the final sql after `strSql = String.Format(strSql, OrderBy, "1=1", rnStart, rnEnd)`? Do you get rows in SSMS if you post it there?

Comment: no rows are showing, Total Rows 0. If I choose only select statement in sql server management , its returning data.

Answer (score 0):

please check this example in ssms and change the accordingly.

```
declare @t table(name varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e')

select ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by name)
, name 

from @t
```

Check the comment, you just apply the "orderby" by value

```
 WITH temptable
     AS (SELECT jobdetails.jobcode,
                jobdetails.currentstatus,
                mastermodel.NAME              AS ModelNumber,
                mastermodel.code              AS ModelCode,
                masterbrand.code              AS BrandCode,
                masterbrand.NAME              AS BrandName,
                masterdevicetype.code         AS DeviceCode,
                masterdevicetype.NAME         AS DType,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY " + orderby + ") AS RowNumber  --here you have to assign the order by  value
         FROM   jobdetails JobDetails
                INNER JOIN masterdevicetype
                        ON jobdetails.dtype = masterdevicetype.code
                INNER JOIN masterbrand
                        ON jobdetails.bcode = masterbrand.code
                INNER JOIN mastermodel
                        ON jobdetails.modelnumber = mastermodel.code
         WHERE  1 = 1)
SELECT *
FROM   temptable
WHERE  rownumber BETWEEN {2} AND {3}
```